# En node js como controlar la programacion asincrona

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Si por ejemplo tengo dos listas de numeros y letras.

```
 var arrayletras = ["a","b","c","d","e"];
var arrayNum = [1,2,3,4];

arrayletras.forEach(function (valLetras) {
    console.log(valLetras+": ");
    arrayNum.forEach(function (valNum) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(valNum);
        },1000)
    })
})
```

Quiero que se muestren primero una letra y despúes todos los números. He leido acerca de callbacks y promesas, pero no lo acabo de solucionar este problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema de `setTimeout` es que simplemente agrega el callback al despachador, luego sigue su curso, es decir no espera que se complete el callback.

En su lugar debes usar funciones asíncronas, y esperar a través de `await` la ejecución de un `Promise`

```js
var arrayLetras = ["a","b","c","d","e"];
var arrayNum = [1,2,3,4];

function sleep(ms)
{
  return new Promise(resolve => { setTimeout(resolve,ms) })
}

async function recorrer(){ 
  for (let letra of arrayLetras) 
    {
      console.log(letra)
      for (let numero of arrayNum)
        {
          console.log(numero)
          await sleep(1000)
        }
    }
}

recorrer()
```

Para más información
1. [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
2. [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)
3. [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Puedes cambiar `for in` por un `for of` para hacerlo más legible.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía ya he modificado el código utilizando `for..of`